I seem to have lost the add rule menu item for CiviRules
I have been looking to update my CiviRules, and add new, but I can’t find the Add rule menu item under CiviRules. I have searched the Civicrm_menu table in MySQL, and it is missing, can someone help with what the path is to the ‘add rule’ in CiviRules so that I can add it back again please?

Here's the url to administer CiviRules: /civicrm/civirules/form/rulesview?reset=1
Here you may add a new one: /civicrm/civirule/form/rule?reset=1&action=add

The menubar is actually called civicrm_navigation in the database, but you don't need to go there. You can add or remove items from the menubar right in the UI, by visiting Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Navigation Menu. Or if that is missing from your menubar(!) you can access it directly at the path civicrm/admin/menu?reset=1.
Also, to double-check the item is really missing and not just misplaced, note that the menubar is searchable: open the green civicrm-logo item in the menubar and start typing a few letters to find what you're looking for.

Just adding that I just had this happen with new install of CiviRules on a Joomla site. The add rule option just was not there at all
This did not work ...
/civicrm/civirule/form/rule?reset=1&action=add
This did
/civicrm/civirule/form/rule&reset=1&action=add

I just loaded CiviRules on the drupal demo site https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org, and see /civicrm/civirule/form/rule?reset=1&action=add
